# Fixed number of records in Crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a SAP Crystal Report in which maximum records I get from database will be 12. The number of records can vary from 0 to 12 depends on the conditions. Now I need to display fixed 12 rows in my Crystal Report regardless of the number of records retrieved from database.

Comment: could you pad the dataset with dummy rows so that it always has 12 records, and then conditionally format the dummy rows to have font color and background color be white, based on a flag only present in the dummy row

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add new rows to your query results or to your `DataTable`, But as you want, I can suggest you a dirty way -That I don't test it yet-:

As you know you can have more than one `Detail` section by inserting new sections below it, and Crystal Report will name them like `a`, `b` and so on.

- Now, You can add 11 detail sections after your current `Detail` section.
- After Adding them you have your `Detail` section with data, and other detail sections that comes below it with an empty row, You can add a rectangle as a border and ... .
- In properties of the section you can set a formula in front of `Suppress` by clicking on formula button, Like this formula -in Crystal Syntax-:

```
if count({your filed}) < 12 then false else true
```

> **Note :**
>   12 is for the second detail section, that will reduced for other sections.

---

For myself in c# I use something like this (as easiest way):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = /* query result */;

for (int i = 12; i > dt.Rows.Count; i--)
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I have done the following. I inserted 11 new detail sections by right clicking on the detail section and selecting "Insert section below". My main data section became a and all other b,c etc..Then I right click on detail b and select section expert and TICK suppress(no drill down) and clicked on the button next and wrote formula       if count({my column name}) < 12 then false else true. And did the same for all other sections by reducing number. Am I doing the correct thing? Now I am getting 11 rows for each actual row. Where is wrong. Please help

Comment: @user2363957 as I found, you just copy and paste the formula, and you forgot the Note, `<12` is just for first section -e.g. `b`- for next it should be `< 11` -e.g `c`, for next `< 10`-e.g `d` and so on to 2 ;).

Comment: I did like that only. But I am getting the same problem

Comment: Make formula field for `if count({your filed}) < ... then false else true` or `count({your filed})` and place it in those sections, to identify what's its result value, It can help us ;).

Comment: Count({sp_bk_get_ExamBookings;1.vBookingID})<12 This is my formula and i placed it in my detail section b and returns true. Now I have 2 records from database. So Two rows are being displayed in my CR and two times I am getting "True" under each actual record from DB. This is my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have the database access.

Create a view with 12 dummy rows and outer join with your table. In this case you will get all 12 rows irrespective of number of rows in data table